# SML - Combine the two lists

Tags: smlnj

I have a question : I know merge two list in SML but i can not do the total number of elements of the first list and the second list is less than n, append them fully and return the resulting list appended with 0’s, totaling n elements.

Sample :

- f2([1,4,5],[3,6],7);
  val it = [1,4,5,3,6,0,0] : int list   // 7 elements

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the length of the two lists with LIST.length and compare the sum with the third argument.

I am not sure what to do if this sum is larger than the third argument but you get the idea.

```
if sum < n then list1 @ list2 @ 0.....
```